# Firebase Javascript, how to use variables from inside ref function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to access a variable from within a datasnapshot:

```
  getEmail() {
    var test = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user).once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        var email = snapshot.val().email;
        });
        console.log(email);
    }
```

That console.log doesn't return the database value, and I am also unable to access that email variable elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Move the log statement up into the scope of the resolved promise. `email` is only defined inside the scope there, so it's only accessible there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: So how would I be able to access the email value outside the scope? Is there another firebase function I could use?

Comment: You can't (in any sensible way) make the value accessible outside of the `then` callback. In other words, everything that relies on that value has to be handled from the `then` callback. The reason is that the value is fetched asynchronously and for the outside scope, which is executed synchronously, to have access to it would require Javascript to have the ability to time travel.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 possible solutions: (both mentioned by Sterling in comments)

1) the log statement is not in the scope of the `.then` method:

```js
getEmail () {
  var test = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user).once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      var email = snapshot.val().email
      console.log(email)
    })
}
```

2.) you could return the `email` variable in the `.then` method and log the `test` variable:

```js
getEmail () {
  var test = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user).once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      var email = snapshot.val().email
      return email
    })
  console.log(test)
}
```

**) clearest way IMO is like this:

```js
getEmail () {
  var email = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user).once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      return snapshot.val().email
    })
  console.log(email)
}
```

Comment: The console.log returns the following object:  Promise {_45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null}. Under the _65 key is where the data I want is stored. Is there a reason the keys are showing up like this?

Comment: try JSON.stringify(email) in the log statement

Comment: also i am guessing you are trying to access the value for the email key which i believe should be as such `return snapshot.child('email').val()`

Answer (score -2):

```js
getEmail () {
  var email = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user).once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      return snapshot.val().email
    })
  console.log(email)
}
```

Comment: That'd set `email` equal to a Promise that would resolve at a later time, not get the actual value from the response